# Asking Postgres to add a non-existent sequence value

Tags: postgresql, auto-increment

I have an existing Postgres table, for example:

```
CREATE TABLE profiles(
  profile_id    SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
  num_feed      integer, 
  num_email     integer, 
  name          text
);

ALTER TABLE ONLY profiles ALTER COLUMN profile_id SET DEFAULT nextval('profiles_profile_id_seq'::regclass);
ALTER TABLE ONLY profiles ADD CONSTRAINT profiles_pkey PRIMARY KEY (profile_id);
CREATE INDEX "pi.profile_id" ON profiles USING btree (profile_id);
```

And this is the existing data, which I can't change, I can only add a new ones.

```
INSERT INTO profiles VALUES
(3, 2, 5, 'Adam Smith'),
(26, 2, 1, 'Fran Morrow'),
(30, 2, 2, 'John Doe'),
(32, 4, 1, 'Jerry Maguire'),
(36, 1, 1, 'Donald Logue');
```

The problem is when I tried to insert a new data, Postgres will add a minimum value (which is good) on column "profile_id" but will failed/error when it hits an existent value, because that value exists.

```
ERROR:  duplicate key value violates unique constraint "profile_id"
DETAIL:  Key (profile_id)=(3) already exists.
```

Is it possible to ask Postgres to add a next non-existent value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dont specify the `SERIAL` field on the insert sentence, let postgres generate it from the sequence for you.

```
INSERT INTO profiles 
 (num_feed,  num_email, name)
VALUES
(2, 5, 'Adam Smith'),
(2, 1, 'Fran Morrow'),
(2, 2, 'John Doe'),
(4, 1, 'Jerry Maguire'),
(1, 1, 'Donald Logue');
```

NOTE: this can fail if after a while you reset the sequence, something like

```
ALTER SEQUENCE 'profiles_profile_id_seq' RESTART WITH 1;
```

Next insert will try to create `1` again and fail.

Comment: For my case, what if I cannot change the existing profile_id. What I can do is to add another. Sorry if it's not very clear from the start. I already edit my question.

Comment: What line give you error? Is that insert you show just after create table ? or much later? As I explain you can use `ALTER SEQUENCE` so the next number is `> max(current_id)`

Comment: You can also try [CURVAL()](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/3281/how-do-i-use-currval-in-postgresql-to-get-the-last-inserted-id) to know what is current seq value. But you also has to remove the serial field from insert

Comment: It gave error when I insert new data, ie: _INSERT INTO profiles (num_feed, num_email, name) VALUES (2, 4, 'John Doe');_
I'll try ALTER_SEQUENCE.

Comment: I decide to change the start value to table max value. Thank you.